# Android SQLite LOCATE

Tags: android, sqlite

Ok, I realize now that my question was too short or something, so I will try my best.

The structured query language of MySQL has a function

```
LOCATE(substr,str)
```

that enables one to restrict a searchquery to a substring that only occures at a certain position, for instance the beginning of the result string. An example would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` 
WHERE REPLACE('searchstring', `mytable`.`columnname`, '') != 'searchstring' 
AND LOCATE(`mytable`.`columnname`, 'searchstring') = 1;
```

By doing so, I tell MySQL to only query a result where the substring I am searching occures at the beginning of said string. I was wondering, how might one achive this using Android SQLite, since Android SQLite doesn't seem to support LOCATE. I also had a look at POSITION, which is also not available on Android.

Comment: Please consider adding a bit more detail, like what research you have done so far, any code you have written (and if you have written then are there any errors, if errors post log). Don't just write a single line statement saying what you want

Comment: Sorry but this is as detailed as it goes. In MySQL there are functions to check out the first occurence of a substring inside a string, for instance LOCATE. In SQLite for Android, this function does not exist. I was wondering what one might use instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no direct SQLite equivalent for `LOCATE`. However, you can get the equivalent of your filter with a `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE mytable.columnname LIKE 'searchstring' || '%';
```

Here I use concatenation (`||`) to append the wildcard `%`, so that you can use a variable to put in place of `searchstring` and not worry about formatting it every time to include the wildcard.

Comment: I'm not too sure about that `REPLACE` logic. Maybe you just don't need it with a `LIKE`. Also, the `LIKE` approach would also work in MySQL.

Comment: The problem with this is that your search won't work if you directly supply the user's text here. IF the search query contains another '%', it will mess up the filter. One way is to inspect the query in Java/Kotlin and remove any of the LIKE operators from the string and then send it to SQlite.